# The results from places autocomplete are not appearing in my google places search

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api

So I'm working on a project that involves **Google Places** and have it to the point where it is correctly parsing existing google places **JSON** results and, as a bonus to the end user, I also implemented a places `autocomplete textview`. All this was working fine. The problems arose when I tried requerying the places api using the autocomplete data that the user had selected through the autocomplete service. I've done some fine gerry rigging to get it working in the first place but often after trying to search for places that are suggested in the autocomplete box, I wind up with no results (which doesn't really make sense).

The only reason I know that autocomplete was working is the fact that the suggestion text pops up in the first place. The only reason I know that the places API is working is that on non-queries I have results and on some queries I have results.

Here is my places search URL that happens on search:

```
    private String BASEURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?";
```

And the parameters added (in the form of an enum) are:

```
    LOCATION("location", ""),
    MINPRICE("minprice", "0"),
    MAXPRICE("maxprice", "4"),
    RADIUS("radius", "0"),
    SENSOR("sensor", "true"),
    OPEN("opennow", "true"),
    KEY("key", BrowserKey),
    KEYWORD("keyword", ""),
    RANKBY("rankby", "distance"),
    TOKEN("pagetoken", "");
```

Which are implemented locally. The real problem is I'm still getting results, but the results that I search for are often either missing or accompanied with other non-relevant results.

TL;DR The results from places autocomplete are not appearing in my google places search

EDIT: Also another quick note is that I have also tried the nearbysearch having altered keyword to query and textsearch all to no avail as well for the places actually being returned properly.

Comment: Ok so I have the places appearing properly by removing minprice, maxprice, and opennow. I was hoping there was a way to ignore these params should they not exist

Comment: Note that if the user picks an Autocomplete prediction with a `place_id` you can simply fetch that specific result via Place Details call (`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=PLACEID&key=...`) without running a search.  This avoids any chance of an ambiguous place name finding unwanted results, and is a simpler response to parse too.

Comment: Thank you, the workaround I decided to implement so that generic search terms were also more accurate was to omit the price range and open now parameters for now. I will be putting in a feature request to have another parameter that, if true, will just mark those as a priority and then return other results based on the query.